# How to change line COUNT for for evil-scroll-up

Tags: spacemacs, evil, scrolling

How to change line COUNT with C-u or C-d for evil-scroll-up or evil-scroll-down?

From Spacemacs help:

```
C-u  (evil-scroll-up COUNT)
C-d  (evil-scroll-down COUNT)
If COUNT is not specified the function scrolls down ‘evil-scroll-count’, which is the last used count.
If the scroll count is zero the command scrolls half the screen.
```

I am using Emacs 26.1 with Evil Spacemacs 0.200.13 and Ivy on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you do it in Vim, by typing the amount of lines you want to scroll, then the command. Alternatively you can provide the numeric argument by typing any of `C-1`..`C-9` or `M-1`..`M-9` or using whatever Spacemacs has mapped the universal argument to, followed by numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to use a spacemacs prefix number argument.

Number:

`3 C-d` scrolls down 3 lines.

`4 C-u C-u` scrolls up 4 lines (the first C-u is unresponsive).

SPC and number:

`SPC 3 C-d` scrolls down 3 lines.

`SPC 4 C-u C-u` scrolls up 4 lines (the first C-u is unresponsive).

Control and number:

`C-3 C-d` scrolls down 3 lines.

`C-4 C-u C-u` scrolls up 4 lines (the first C-u is unresponsive).